# Passing arguments and checking their length

Tags: shell, unix

I am learning shell and i would like to find out how to pass arguments into variables using command line (no using scripts) and checking arguments length. For example i want to type 10 20 into command line and want to output numbers between them , i tried

```
    for((i=$1;i<$2;i++))do echo "$1"; done // or
    a=$1
    b=$2
    for((i=$a;i<$b;i++))do echo "$1"; done
```

but nothing works , also i would like to check the number of arguments but fail to find and source for it , as i mentioned i want to do it using command line not using scripts and executing them

Comment: How are you intending to get "arguments" on the command line directly? What are you expecting `$1` and `$2` to contain here/at your interactive prompt?

Answer (score 0):

At a raw prompt, the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) are usually not set.  You can set them, but it's weird.   For your case, you could do:

```
$ set 10 20  # set $1 and $2
$ i=$1
$ while test $i -lt $2; do echo $((i++)); done
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

or

```
$ foo() { i=${1:?}; while test $i -lt ${2:?}; do echo $((i++)); done; }
$ foo 10 20
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```